# Javascript - Input Value NaN

Tags: javascript

Im new to Javascript and i was doing some DOM maniputalion, and i tried to create the BMI (body mass index) calculator, which is bodyMass / ( bodyWeight * bodyWeight ).

Then i've done some code:

HTML:

```js
var bodyMass, bodyWeight;
bodyMass = parseInt(document.getElementById("bodyMass").value, 10);
bodyWeight = parseInt(document.getElementById("bodyWeight").value, 10);
var BMI = bodyMass / (bodyWeight * bodyWeight);
document.getElementById("check").onclick = function() {
  alert(BMI);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Body Mass" id="bodyMass">
<input type="text" placeholder="Body Weight" id="bodyWeight">
<button id="check">CHECK</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Please review [ask] and update your post to include an actual question.

Comment: Are you dividing by zero? Hint: Write a function that does the calculations for you, then feed it values in a controlled way to verify it works properly before integrating with your application.

Comment: The problem is simply that you're calculating `bodyMass` and `bodyWeight` **outside of the click event**. Those variables get set as soon as the page loads, at which point they are *empty*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to calculate the body mass index when the button is clicked, not on page load. By not placing your code inside the event handler, you are calculating everything before any values are entered.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Body Mass" id="bodyMass">
<input type="text" placeholder="Body Weight" id="bodyWeight">
<button id="check">CHECK</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
var bodyMass, bodyWeight;

document.getElementById("check").onclick = function() {
bodyMass = parseInt(document.getElementById("bodyMass").value, 10);
bodyWeight = parseInt(document.getElementById("bodyWeight").value, 10);
var BMI = bodyMass / (bodyWeight * bodyWeight);
  alert(BMI);
}
</script>
```

To make sure the value is not `NaN` before alerting, you use `isNaN`.

```html
 <input type="text" placeholder="Body Mass" id="bodyMass">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Body Weight" id="bodyWeight">
    <button id="check">CHECK</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script>
    var bodyMass, bodyWeight;

    document.getElementById("check").onclick = function() {
    bodyMass = parseInt(document.getElementById("bodyMass").value, 10);
    bodyWeight = parseInt(document.getElementById("bodyWeight").value, 10);
    var BMI = bodyMass / (bodyWeight * bodyWeight);
    if(!isNaN(BMI)){
      alert(BMI);
    } else {
     alert("Please enter two valid numbers!");
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: ohhh, so i just needed to put everything inside the function?

Comment: @AndreLança That's it.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the values of bodyWeigt and bodyMass even before the button is clicked, at this stage (after parseInt-ing them) they are of course not a number (NaN).

Grab the values on click of the button i.e when the user has (hopefully) entered some valid values...

```js
document.getElementById("check").onclick = function() {
var bodyMass, bodyWeight;
bodyMass = parseInt(document.getElementById("bodyMass").value);
bodyWeight = parseInt(document.getElementById("bodyWeight").value);
var BMI = bodyMass / (bodyWeight * bodyWeight); 
  alert(BMI);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="Body Mass" id="bodyMass">
<input type="number" placeholder="Body Weight" id="bodyWeight">
<button id="check">CHECK</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Because your input are numeric, you should instead do

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Body Mass" id="bodyMass">
<input type="number" placeholder="Body Weight" id="bodyWeight">
```

and place the calculation inside the button click `event`, else the calculation will get executed once the page loads and you will get a `NaN` alert.